# How to post my currently playing song to my website?

Tags: itunes, html, music, winamp, foobar2000

I need to publish my currently playing song info to my website. I have three media players on my desktop: Winamp, iTunes and foobar2000. I mostly listen with Winamp, and sometimes iTunes or foobar.

Is there any way to publish or post song information to my website? Information like track title/artist/album/year/genre et cetera?

I need to display it on an HTML page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a [tutorial for this on my blog](http://117.synergize.co/index.html?post=ajax_html_02).

Tools required:

- [AMIP for Winamp](http://amip.tools-for.net/ds/dl.php?f=/files/amip_winamp.zip)
- For foobar / iTunes users, check for [AMIP plugin on their website](http://amip.tools-for.net/wiki/amip/download)
- [AMIP Configurator](http://amip.tools-for.net/ds/dl.php?f=/files/amip_config.zip)
- [Winamp 5+](http://www.winamp.com/)
- [Dropbox](http://www.dropbox.com)
- Notepad

Javascript files required:

- [jQuery Library](http://www.jquery.com/)

Method:

1. Download and install AMIP & Configurator. Copy the following code to `Callbacks/Web` tab in the configurator.

   ```
   /template:(C:\Users\_USERNAME_\Dropbox\Public\in.html) C:\Users\_USERNAME_\Dropbox\Public\out.html
   ```

   Replace `_USERNAME_` with your Windows login username (location of your Dropbox).
2. Open the Dropbox folder: `Dropbox\Public\`

   Create a new HTML document in this folder called `in.html` and add the following variable to it: `%name`

   You can get more variables and functions [on the AMIP website](http://amip.tools-for.net/wiki/manual/amip).

   So, contents of the `in.html` would be:

   %name
3. Now we start with coding the `index.html` page. Copy this file to your `/js/` folder: `jquery.min.js`

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>

   <script>
   $(function(){
      $.get("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/27854284/out.html", function(data) {
         $("#nowPlayingInfo").html(data);
      });
   });
   </script>
   ```
4. Code for the main body tags of `index.html`. Add the following code to your body tag where the Song information will be displayed.

   ```
   <p><span id="nowPlayingInfo">Artist - Song Title</span></p>
   ```

That completes the answer.

Detailed explanation of code and scripts [are provided on my blog](http://117.synergize.co/index.html?post=ajax_html_02). The demo is [on my homepage](http://117.synergize.co/) is inactive presently...

Comment: An explanation of *how* this works might make this a better answer; right now there is no information as to what it is that you'd be doing if you followed these directions. Link is broken. Is that your blog?

Comment: Yes! That's my blog, and I just forgot to publish my post before answering this. The blog link is active now... you only need to download the source files.zip to view how this is being done. If not, then I'll post a demo as well.

Comment: Where is the connection to foobar in your answer?

Comment: AMIP supports foobar as well... you only have to install foobar plugin from amip website and the rest of the process is the same!

Comment: I copyedited your post. Please have a look at the source (click [edit]) and try to format code and lists correctly – when in a list, code needs to be indented by 8 spaces instead of 4. Also, using inline links makes the post more readable.

Answer (score 1):

For foobar2000 it is better to use http://skipyrich.com/wiki/Foobar2000:Now_Playing_Simple , because AMIP does not support last foobar2000 version.
Also, you can share js files on dropbox too, just replace 'www.dropbox.com' with 'dl.dropboxusercontent.com' in public links.

Now_Playing_Simple also support UTF-8 and datetime stamp.

Comment: AMIP does support the latest foobar2000 version.